# How can I structure Firebase FCM token storage to scale?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

My web app will have a chat feature that works based on "threads" and "messages".

In any given thread, 2 or more people can be subscribed for notifications of new messages.

Any given person can have multiple devices, each with a corresponding FCM token (acquired after permission is given to send them notifications).

Say I have a thread "cats" with 3 subscribers. Document structure like this:

```
id: "thread1"
  title: "cats"
  subscribers:["uid1","uid2","uid3"]
```

and I have FCM tokens stored for those three users. Document structure like this:

```
id: "token1"
  tokenOwner: "uid1"
id: "token2"
  tokenOwner: "uid2"
id: "token3"
  tokenOwner: "uid2"
id: "token4"
  tokenOwner: "uid3"
id: "token5"
  tokenOwner: "uid4"
```

To send a notification for new messages in `thread1`, I need to query the FCM Tokens collection for any token where `tokenOwner` is in the supplied array `["uid1","uid2","uid3"]`.

That query would look something like this:

```
db
  .collection("fcmTokens")
  .where('tokenOwner', 'in', ["uid1","uid2","uid3"])
  .get()...
```

This works great until Cloud Firestore query limitations kick in:

> Use the in operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the
>   same field with a logical OR. An in query returns documents where the
>   given field matches any of the comparison values.

I can only include up to 10 uid's in the array query. If 12 people are subscribed to the thread, I'm either out of luck or need to run multiple queries which seems inefficient.

How can I structure FCM tokens in a way that is "Firebase Friendly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running multiple queries for this situation is not really inefficient.  All the requests are pipelined over a single connection, and you should be able to get them all in milliseconds of time over a fast connection.  The new "in" queries are mostly intended to be a convenience layer for not having to do multiple queries, not so much intended to be an optimization (unless it prevents you from fetching the same document multiple times from multiple queries).  You should be fine with what you have now - no need to prematurely optimize this until you actually observe a performance problem.

Personally, I would store tokens for a user organized under UID of the user, rather than have all the users' tokens together in one collection.

```
Collection: user-tokens
  Document ID: {uid}
    - tokens: [ array of tokens for the user ]
```

Then, to get all the tokens for a user, simply get their doc that contains all the tokens.

If you're worried that user could be using thousands of devices and the number of tokens could outsize the capacity of a single document, then store each token in a separate document, and query the entire subcollection for a user's tokens:

```
Collection: user-tokens
  Document ID: {uid}
    Subcollection: tokens
      Document ID: {random}
        - token: string
```

Organizing tokens under the UID also makes it easier to write security rules so that only a particular user can read and write their own tokens, if that's something you'd like to control.

Comment: Just putting this here, the limitation of this approach is that the read requests (so does cost) increase when the more users you have in a thread